# Understanding dot notation

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's my interpretation of dot notation:

```
a = [2,6]
b = [1,4]
c = [0,8]
a . b . c = (2*6)+(1*4)+(0*8) = 12 + 4 + 0 = 16
```

What is the significance of 16? Apparently it's a scalar.

Am I right in thinking that a scalar is the number we times a unit vector by to get a vector that has a scaled up magnitude but the same direction as the unit vector? So again, what is the relevance of 16? When is it used? It's not the magnitude of all the vectors added up.

The magnitude of all of them is calculated as follows:

```
sqrt( ax * ax + ay * ay ) + sqrt( bx * bx + by * by ) + sqrt( cx * cx + cy * cy)
sqrt( 2 * 2 + 6 * 6 ) + sqrt( 1 * 1 + 4 * 4 ) + sqrt( 0 * 0 + 8 * 8)
sqrt( 4 + 36 ) + sqrt( 1 + 16 ) + sqrt( 0 + 64)
sqrt( 40 ) + sqrt( 17 ) + sqrt( 64)
6.3 + 4.1 + 8
10.4 + 8
18.4
```

So I don't really get this diagram:

[image: dot notation]

Attempting with sensible numbers:

```
a = [1,0]
b = [4,3]

a . b = (1*0) + (4*3) = 0 + 12 = 12
```

So what exactly is `a . b` describing here? The magnitude of that vector? Because that isn't right:

```
the 'a.b' vector = [4,0]
sqrt( x*x + y*y )
sqrt( 4*4 + 0*0 )
sqrt( 16 + 0 )
4
```

So what is 12 describing?

Comment: If I have two vectors `a = [ax, ay]` and `b = [bx, by]`, then `dot(a, b) = ax * bx + ay * by`. What you've shown above is `ax * ay + bx * by`, which is not a standard dot product.

If the vector a has length one (as in the bottom diagram), then `Dot(a, b)` is the length of the projection of `b` onto the axis represented by `a`. `Dot(a, b) * a` is a vector in the direction of `a` with this length - that's the red arrow on the right in the bottom diagram.

Comment: @DMGregory Hmm bit of a stupid error on my part. Is this equation correct for describing dot notation: http://postimg.org/image/pohr31pw7/

Comment: No, that is not a standard dot product. Try this one from Wikipedia:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/3/2/c329bf86e747d74f55ed2e17c36fd83f.png

Comment: Thanks, what do you make of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814104/equation-to-describe-dot-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did your dot product wrong as DMGregory pointed out...

Anyways this is the formula for a dot product, which answers your question but probably isn't useful to you so I'll cover where I've found dot product useful.

```
A·B = |A|*|B|*cos(Θ)

|A| is the lenght of A
|B| is the lenght of B
Θ is the angle between A and B using 0,0 as a pivot
```

The dot product is typically used for telling where a an object is in relation to movement. If 0,0 is current location and A is the movement vector and B is an object we can tell 3 things about it from the result of the dot product.

1. If A and B are perpendicular (at 90 degrees to each other), the result of the dot product will be zero, because cos(Θ) will be zero.
2. If the angle between A and B are less than 90 degrees, the dot product will be positive (greater than zero), as cos(Θ) will be positive, and the vector lengths are always positive values.
3. If the angle between A and B are greater than 90 degrees, the dot product will be negative (less than zero), as cos(Θ) will be negative, and the vector lengths are always positive values.

You can extend from that and assuming all vectors are normalized you can the below which allows for easy line of sight checking.

```
θ = acos(D'V')
```

D is the direction the object doing the seeing is pointing. 
V is the direction from the object diong the seeing to the object we are checking is in the line of sight.

So for example if the cone of vision was 90degrees any result of θ below 45degrees would be in the line of sight.

I'm a bit rusty on this stuff so feel free to call me out on errors.

Comment: I can see how it could be useful, but I haven't come across timsing the whole thing by *cos(Θ)...

Comment: When looking for math resources look for GameDev specific resources, they will include relevant examples. Also I recommend checking out http://www.essentialmath.com/tutorial.htm.

Comment: The cos(theta) is implicit in the definition. If you have two vectors a=[ax, ay], b=[bx, by] with an angle of theta between them, then `Dot(a, b) = ax*bx + ay*by = magnitude(a) * magnitude(b) * cos(theta)`. All three forms represent the same value, just different ways of thinking about it.